# Extract thread dump from a heap dump

Tags: java, jvm, dump, eclipse-mat

I have a huge heap dump (around 12GB) and it will take forever to open it with `MAT` or `jvisualvm`. I only want to get the thread dump out of it without indexing the objects. Is it possible with the above or any other tools?

Comment: Is that a file obtained with `jmap`?

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem recently.

I just pushed the project doing it on GitHub.
I know, it is way too late, but probably will save some time to someone in future.

https://github.com/aafomin/obadiah

Comment: Sounds awesome, I will give it a try some day

Comment: You're still here ) ok, i hope it will be useful

Comment: Is this tool is still available somewhere? (GitHub shows HTTP 404 instead)

Answer (score 0):

The latest snapshot versions of Memory Analyzer (preview of 1.11) have the ability to discard objects on parse.
Having a discard ratio of 100% with a pattern of (?!.*Thread).* would discard all objects
except those of a type with 'Thread' in the classname.
That might speed up parsing, though the parsed dump would be nearly useless, but it would have a thread dump (but without thread names or local variables) which might be enough for your purposes.